# Ionic content scrolling up issue when keyboard is open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

When we open keyboard, the all content scrolling up in app screen.
We are already added this code, but still not working.

```
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) { 
    window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true); 
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This should be `false` window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same issue with ionic v4

the keyboard moves the ion-virtual-scroll when the keyboard is shown